# A certified copy for Australian PR visa

Tags: visa, australia, pr, certification

ACS requirements state that I need to submit a certified copy.

I will go to the Australian embassy to do this, but am just not sure ...

**Will they certify a document that I print out (scanned signature) or does it need to be the exact document signed.**

This is in regards to the skills assessment employment references letters. I need to know if I need to make my past employers post me the document on email it to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A certified copy of any document can be done by a big list of people in australia.  Embassy staff are able to do this and work at the embassies for this purpose.  No one will ever issue a certified copy of a document without sighting the original document. A good description is here: [Smart Traveller - Documents](http://smartraveller.gov.au/services/legalising-documents/Pages/overseas.aspx)

With that said if it's a letter from an employer that may have been emailed in the first place, thats all you really need to say (it was sent to me via email in the first place) and they'll likely certify it for you.  I don't know if the reference is in english, but if it's not you could get a translation done and then have that original translation certified.